# Access Class Method from Another Class Instance, Python Syntax

Tags: python, pandas, syntax

I am new in python and trying to understand the following syntax in Pandas:

```
df['new']=df['category'].str.split('-')
```

So `df['category']` is of type `pandas.core.series.Series` but

`df['category'].str` is of type `pandas.core.strings.accessor.StringMethods`

So an instance of `Series` class can access methods of `StringMethods` class, right ?

How is this possible ? No need to explain in detail, just a link to some source that provides this functionality would suffice.

Comment: A `Series` object has an attribute `str` which is a `StringMethods` object…

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I don't understand why there is any confusion. "How is this possible ?" The same way that `df` can be a DataFrame while `df['category']` is a Series. "So an instance of "Series" class can access methods of "StringMethods" class right ?" No; using `.str` on a Series gives you a StringMethods. It has nothing to do with the methods of that class. That happens in the **next** step.

Comment: It's a construct specific to pandas. the 'str' in the name is arbitrary. it's a way to separate string-related manipulation methods from other Series methods

Comment: deceze, Karl Knectel, KishKas Thank you all very much!